# Cannot drag URL using chromium/chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, chromium

Here is a [demo page](https://liutianren.com/s/example.html) that shows the problem.

The page contains only one link.  Using Firefox, I can drag the URL from the link.  But with Chromium or Chrome, I cannot.

[image]

Actually, in Chromium/Chrome I can drag the URL from the left margin of the inner `div`.  This looks weird.

How should I modify the page so that I can drag the URL from Chromium/Chrome?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>/</title>
  <style>
    div.border {
      border: 2px solid black;
    }
    div.item {
      margin: 10px 30px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="border">
    <a href="downloads/">
      <div class="item">downloads</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If with dragging you refer to drag the link to open it on a new tab (for example), then chrome should do it correctly. What is causing your problem is the div you've got inside.

Comment: In this case, I cannot _drag the link to open it on a new tab_, unless I start the dragging on a weird region (just updated my question to highlight the region).